# Is there a fast way to find a pair of points in a pointcloud or mesh to determine geodesic distance?

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh, point-clouds, open3d

I have a point cloud of a mask as seen here. A long set of X,Y, and Z coordinates.
[image: Text]

I want to find the geodesic distance from the tip of the nose to the center of the top lip. This would be the distance down the contour of the nose, as opposed to the Euclidian distance which would be a straight line.

What is the easiest and fastest way to do this?

I am thinking of two ways:

1. Train a PointNet model to identify the nose and the lip and find the points of intersection. Then run a post hoc algorithm to find the geodesic distance between the two points. (Still unsure if I can identify the exact coordinates I need)
2. Convert the point cloud to a mesh and perhaps there is some secondary software that can provide a solution.
3. Currently, I am doing a guess and check method where I find the "extremes" and work my way down with educated guesses. But it has already taken me 2 hours to find a point. Clearly not scalable.

Comment: The node is the highest point in the direction orthogonal to the plane. The lip-point is about half-way between the nose and the chin. "geodesic distance between two points pointcloud" returns several promising papers in google scholar.

Comment: Thanks- I was thinking of using geometric rules like that, but once I start looking for other features, such as distance between eyelid and center of eye, I can't rely too much on that. Hence, I was thinking of part segmentation using PointNet, but I can't find any clear guides on how I can get started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Open3D supports this out of the box, but I remember [libIGL does](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/#exact-discrete-geodesic-distances)

[image: libIGL geodesic distance]

libIGL has [Python bindings](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/), but double check [license](https://libigl.github.io/license/) is something you can use.

You might need to convert your pointcloud to a mesh, but Open3D's [surface reconstruction](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/surface_reconstruction.html?highlight=reconstruction) (or maybe [voxelise](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/jupyter/geometry/voxelization.html?highlight=voxel) the pointcloud).

There might other options than libIGL out there too.